# Inverse functions: what is the difference between $\tan^{-1}(x)$ and $\tan(x)^{-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, notation, inverse

I’ve never really been taught about inverse functions, and I figured this is a pretty simple question, but I couldn’t find any explanation in my math textbook about this.

What is the difference between $\tan^{-1}$ and $\tan(x)^{-1}$?

Comment: Usually $\tan (x) ^{-1}$ denotes the inverse value of the number $\tan (x)$ (if $\tan (x) \neq 0$), while $\tan^{-1} (x)$ denotes the arctan function - the inverse of $\tan (x)$. Of course, these are just conventions...

Answer (score 2):

$\tan^{-1}$ denotes the inverse tangent function, AKA the arc tangent (the angle the tangent of which is the given number). When applied to an argument, you spell

$$\tan^{-1}(x)=\arctan(x).$$

As far as I know, 
$$\tan(x)^{-1}$$
can be interpreted as the reciprocal of the tangent, i.e. the cotangent

$$\frac1{\tan(x)},$$ and it is safer to write
$$(\tan(x))^{-1}=\cot(x).$$

Of course, this differs from

$$\tan(x^{-1})=\tan\left(\frac1x\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan^{-1}$ would normally denote the FUNCTION $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ given by sending $x$ to the unique $y$ satisfying $\tan(y)=x$, while $\tan(x)^{-1}$ presumably stands for the real NUMBER, which is the multiplicative inverse $\frac{1}{\tan x}$ and is well-defined whenever $\tan(x)\neq 0$, i.e. whenever $x$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.